# Retrieve contents of objects from Plone using Python script

Tags: python, scripting, plone

I am using Plone 5. I have added a Python script and what I am trying to do is to get the objects contained in one of the folders and print them. I used `context.restrictedTraverse(path)` to get an object by path but it only returns `<Document at path>` . Does anyone have any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: "<Document at ...>" is how Python represents a Document object as a string. If you want to print it's attributes, you'll need to access them individually. Or, call a view on a document to get it's HTML representation.

Comment: If I have folders and there are different pages in one of them, what I want to do is to get the contents of those pages, one by one or display two pages at a time. But I could only go as far as getting the pages' names. Is there any way to get the actual contents?(text on the page)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only traversing to the document.

Here a list of some possible methods to get the children of a folder.

```
>>> # List all children without security checks
>>> context.restrictedTraverse(path).objectValues()

>>> # List all ids without security checks
>>> context.restrictedTraverse(path).objectIds()

>>> # List all ids/values without security checks
>>> context.restrictedTraverse(path).contentItems()

>>> # You can use the catalog, this includes security checks and more.
>>> # This will return a catalog results (brains), not the actual object.
>>> context.restrictedTraverse(path).objectIds().getFolderContents()
```

For further informations please check the plone docu page: http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/content/listing.html